# Unable to set lastModifyingUser.displayName on file in Shared Drive

Tags: file, google-apps-script, parameters

I have successfully copied a file (file.makeCopy) from a My Drive folder to a Shared Drive folder. I want to set the lastModifyingUser.displayName. The code executes but the displayName is not updated. However, the modifiedDate is successfuly set. Here's the code:

```
Drive.Files.patch( // Restore the original last-modified date and last modifying user
  {
    modifiedDate: originalFileLastUpdatedDate.toISOString(),
    lastModifyingUser: {
      displayName: originalFileLastModifiedBy
    }
  },
    copiedFileId,
  {
    setModifiedDate: true,
    supportsAllDrives: true
  });
```

The debugger tells me that originalFileLastModifiedBy is a text string containing a user's name, but it doesn't update the file's parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this any particular language?

Comment: I should have been more specific. This is a snippet of Google Apps Scripting.

Comment: It turns out that this field is not writable, per https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files.